# SQL joined subquery problem / performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to write a query to obtain the same result set as the following "imaginary" query?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_report AS
    SELECT
        meta.refnum         AS  refnum,
        codes.svc_codes     AS  svc_codes
    FROM
        t_bill AS meta

    JOIN (SELECT
        string_agg(p.service_code, ':') AS svc_codes
      FROM
        t_bill_service_services AS p
      WHERE
        p.refnum = meta.refnum
    ) AS codes
    ON meta.refnum = codes.refnum
```

This query is imaginary because it won't run with an error message about the `meta.refnum` in the `WHERE` clause not being able to be referenced from this part of the query.

Note 1: many columns from a variety of other tables which are also JOINed are omitted in the interest of brevity.  This may preclude some simpler solutions which eliminate the subquery.

Note 2: it is possible to make this work (for some definitions of "work") by adding the `p.refnum` column to the subquery and doing a `GROUP BY p.refnum` and removing the `WHERE` altogether, but this of course means the entire t_bill_service_services table gets scanned and sorted -- very *very* slow for my situation, as the table is reasonably large.

(The SQL flavor is Postgres, but should be irrelevant, as only the `string_agg()` call should be non-std SQL.)

Comment: If you write the subquery in the `SELECT` instead of as a `JOIN` you should be able to access `meta.refnum` e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4f8053f501d5edc2fd2fba3e3560e7ac

Comment: Could you elucidate and maybe provide an example in an Answer?  I'll happily vote it up and mark it as accepted if it works.

Comment: Did you look at the demo link?

Comment: Yup.  Seems to work.  Thanks much.  Thought you might want to get credit for the answer.  :-)

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. If you're happy with it I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Happy with it!      (Strangely, I had originally tried a subquery in my `SELECT` but encountered an odd error which mislead me to think I couldn't use one in my situation.  PEBKAC or something.)

Comment: I can't believe I've never encountered PEBKAC! Brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `JOIN`ing to a derived table, you can place the subquery in the `SELECT` part of the query. In this section, you can access the values from the parent table in subqueries and so only aggregate the relevant entries in the other table. For example:

```
select meta.refnum,
       (SELECT string_agg(p.service_code, ':')
        FROM t_bill_service_services AS p
        WHERE p.refnum = meta.refnum
       ) AS svc_codes
from t_bill meta
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4f8053f501d5edc2fd2fba3e3560e7ac)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a lateral join -- and Postgres supports these.  You can write the query as:

```
SELECT meta.refnum         AS  refnum,
       codes.svc_codes     AS  svc_codes
FROM t_bill meta CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT string_agg(p.service_code, ':') AS svc_codes
      FROM t_bill_service_services p
      WHERE p.refnum = meta.refnum
     ) codes;
```

In this case, a lateral join is a lot like a correlated subquery (Nick's answer).  However, a lateral join is much more powerful, because it allows the subquery to return multiple columns and multiple rows.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for answering.